# Failed to update a TargetChangeListener

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I was making a simple application. When I added third `Activity` to my project, Eclipse started giving me following error in Error logs

> Failed to update a TargetChangeListener.

I have tried clean/build project but that removed my `R.java` file and start showing

> No resource found that matches the given name

for all resources. Can anybody tell the reason behind this error and how can I resolve this?

Following is the complete error:

```
eclipse.buildId=v22.6.2-1085508
java.version=1.7.0_55
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments: -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
Command-line arguments: -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product

Error Sat May 17 23:21:10 PKT 2014 Failed to update a TargetChangeListener.

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderService.<init>(RenderService.java:129)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.RenderService.create(RenderService.java:226)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1578)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1309)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.changed(GraphicalEditorPart.java:725)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.onTargetChange(GraphicalEditorPart.java:1196) 
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditorDelegate.onDescriptorsChanged(LayoutEditorDelegate.java:916)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditorDelegate.delegateInitUiRootNode(LayoutEditorDelegate.java:835)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart$TargetListener.updateEditor(GraphicalEditorPart.java:953)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart$TargetListener.onTargetLoaded(GraphicalEditorPart.java:917)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.AdtPlugin$11.run(AdtPlugin.java:1759)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4145)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3762)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332) 
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1426)
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  Would love to know if you found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must update the Android SDK version.
go to android sdk manager and check for update concern with API Level